# SQL - not equal to operator is ignoring the rest of the where clause

Tags: sql

```
product_id |value
1          | a
1          | b
1          | c
2          | a
2          | c
2          | d
3          | a
3          | c
3          | d
```

Below is my code, what I am trying to achieve with it is to check which product_id's have both 'a' and 'c' -that part works fine.

My problem is that when i do the following:

```
AND value != ('b')
```

It completely ignores the not equal to operator and still returns b...

```
SELECT 
    product_id, value
FROM
          table
WHERE
    value = 'a'
    OR value = 'c'
    AND value != ('b')
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING count(value) = 2
order by product_id
```

I guess my question is how do I fix it and why is this happening? thank you very much for your time. :)

EDIT:
What I should achieve is :

```
product_id  value
2   a
3   a
```

Comment: Parantheses, parantheses, parantheses....

Comment: Although most probably not relevant for your question, you should always add a tag for your specific DBMS (`postgresql`, `oracle`, ...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name IIRC, mysql is the only dbms where `!=` is used instead of `<>` ;-]

Comment: @wildplasser: that's not true. While `<>` is the operator defined by the SQL standard all DBMS I know also accept the non-standard `!=` operator

Comment: @wildplasser you are wrong. Sql server provides such possibility.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add proper parenthesis to the `where` clause. Now the And operator is applied between `value='C' and value<>'b'`

```
SELECT 
    product_id, value
FROM
          table
WHERE
    (value = 'a'
    OR value = 'c')
    AND value != ('b')
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING count(value) = 2
order by product_id
```

**Update :** : looks like fixing parenthesis will not fix your problem. Use `conditional count` in `having` clause to filter the groups.

```
SELECT product_id,
       min(value) value
FROM   table
GROUP  BY product_id
HAVING Count(CASE WHEN value = 'a' THEN 1 END) = 1
       AND Count(CASE WHEN value = 'c' THEN 1 END) = 1
       AND Sum(CASE WHEN value <> 'b' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: that still produces 
    product_id  value
    1   a
    2   a
    3   a

im trying to completely remove product_id = 1 as it has b has its value. but both 2 and 3 dont have b so they should appear

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you very much. been stuck on this for a while so it feels amazing to be able to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations.

```
value = 'a' OR value = 'c' AND value <> ('b')
```

will evaluate the same as

```
value = 'a' OR (value = 'c' AND value <> ('b'))
```

Change your conditional (WHERE) clause to

```
(value = 'a' OR value = 'c') AND value <> ('b')
```